# Swift setGradientBackground does not work after changing Width constant

Tags: swift

I am trying to change the gradient background after I change the width.

I first setup the storyboard.  I then apply a constraint for the width.

in the controller I can change everything fine - expect .setGradientBackground.

It only applies the gradient to the original storyboard width settings.

[image]

Here is the view controller code:

```
import UIKit

class _textVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var test: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var testWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let c1 = UIColor.green
    let c2 = UIColor.white

    testWidth.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width  * 0.8
    test.layer.cornerRadius = 10;

    test.setGradientBackground(colorOne: c1, colorTwo: c2)

  }

}
```

I got the function from a Sean Allen YouTube but I have tried other functions with the same effect.

```
func setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor) {

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)

    layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

}
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is best answer but I got it to work.

I had to move it out of the viewDidLoad.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    let c1 = Color.lightShade
    let c2 = Color.darkShade

    testWidth.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width  * 0.8
    test.setGradientBackground(colorOne: c1, colorTwo: c2)

}
```

Comment: add viewDidLayoutSubviews()  to your view controller